# email template security

Tags: email-template, permissions

Can we secure email templates to restrict usage within an organization?  We have a couple of email templates that we want to make available to only a couple of people in the organization and wondering if there was a way to do this.  If not, does anyone have suggestions for an alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, to an extent. Email templates are stored in folders, each of which can have separate security policies. When you create a new folder, you can set it to be either Public Read Only or Public Read/Write, but further down are the sharing settings:

1. This folder is accessible by all users
2. This folder is hidden from all users
3. This folder is accessible only by the following users

If you choose option 3, you can give access by:

1. Public groups
2. Roles
3. Roles and Subordinates

If you only need a few users to have access, the Public Group route is probably your best option.

See [Creating and Editing Folders](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_and_editing_folders.htm) for more information.