# SOQL query on Email Template is not returning any results

Tags: apex, email-template, sharing-rule

I got a weird error while performing an operation from the Salesforce community. I was saving a record through portal and due to the same a record triggered flow was getting fired. That record triggered flow was further calling an apex method which is having an SOQL on Email_Template object. The class in which the method was present was in `with sharing`.

The SOQL query is not returning any results. As soon as I'm changing the sharing context to `without sharing`, it is working fine.

I'm unable to understand why it is happening. I tried adding the same SOQL in some other Aura Enabled method present in a `with sharing` class and this time it worked fine.

In both the above cases the profile and the sharing context were the same. The only difference is, one is an Aura Enabled method and one is an Invocable method getting called from a flow.

Does the Email Template object respect sharing?

Comment: related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/18344/2602